# Excel data import with restrictions

Tags: excel, vba, csv, import, restrict

Hello friendly people :)

**Background info:**

I have a python script which takes creates an ad-hoc BI report gathering various data from SQL servers and doing the necessary calculations. The output is dumped as a .CSV file on a common drive.

To make the output more user-friendly, the CSV is imported into an excel spreadsheet with various formatting to make it easier to read. This spreadsheet is used by many different users, but never at the same time.

The problem is that, the end user will type various inputs into the spreadsheet which are then factored in the next time the python script is run. An example could be marking a row with an 'x' to denote "this problem has already been dealt with" so that it does not appear in the next output.

The problem arises, if a user re-imports the data from the csv without the underlying script having been run. This effectively deletes all the user markings making people do double work.

It's a horrible set-up i know, but it will have to make due for now. Corporate is not willing to integrate it into the ERP system before proof of concept has been demonstrated.

**Question:**

Is it possible in excel to implement a data import restriction saying that the CSV file can only be imported if the files time-stamp is recent, say within the last hour? Currently I am just using the standard text-import, and it does not seem to have this feature.

I imagine it would be easier to make a VBA macro button, but i seldom do work in excel and I haven't got the slightest idea as how to proceed.

I am imagining a button which does the following written in my own pseudo_code:

```
 Press button():
     if (datetime.now - time_stamp_csv_file) < 1 hour:
        import file
     else:
         do nothing
```

If anyone has got any kinf of solution that works, I will be a happy person.

Comment: Not convinced about the approach to the whole thing.. but then like you said, it's not your call. But if you want to add a button in your sheet to be able to do this then do a search for **button in a sheet with macro**. There are a lot of examples out there.. here is one: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/878-excel-insert-macro-button.html

Comment: Thanks Zac, perhaps I should clarify the level i'm operating at. I know how to insert a macro-button and find other peoples code to put into it, but modifying that code in any way shape or form atm. is beyond me. Honestly. I literally have no idea what I am looking at. 

Attempts at retro-fitting an if-statement into an otherwise working script hasn't been very successful thus far :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you already have code to import the file and just need to know how to check the last modified timestamp.  If that's the case, you should be able to use something like this:

```
Sub ImportButton_Click()

    Dim oFSO As Object
    Dim oFile As Object

    Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFile = oFSO.GetFile("C:\Test\Test.csv")            'Change this to your actual CSV file path

    If Now() - oFile.DateLastModified < TimeValue("01:00:00") Then
        'import file
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! 

I even think your answer made something about basic VBA syntax click for me :)